# Erro ao fazer conexão MySQL usando .NET. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, mysql

Exceção ao conectar ao banco:

> IsPasswordExpired: 'conn.IsPasswordExpired' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>
> ServerThread: 'conn.ServerThread' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>
> ServerVersion: 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Exceção ao tentar abrir a conexão:

> "The type initializer for
>   'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception."

```
public static MySqlConnection Conexao()
{
   string strConexao = "Server=ip_do servidor_de bd;Port=3306;Database=meubanco;Uid=usuario;Pwd=senha;";
   MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
   conn = new MySqlConnection(strConexao);

   conn.Open();

   return conn;
}
```

Comment: Tem dois erros citados na sua pergunta, mas o primeiro não parece corresponder ao snipet postado. Pode melhorar a pergunta por gentileza?

Comment: Em relação ao primeiro erro: Verifica se sua senha do mysql não expirou, o padrão é a senha durar 1 ano(Exceto se você alterou a configuração).